# How can I set up Zk Sessions (org.zkoss.zk.ui) so I can unit test a controller class extending GenericForwardComposer

Tags: java, unit-testing, zk

I'm trying to unit test an existing ZK controller and I want to find a way to handle a call like the following while unit testing my Controller,

```java
Sessions.getCurrent().setAttribute("from", from.getValue());
```

I'd be happy to either replacing the offending code, or find a way around it for the unit test. My goal is testability by dealing with the `NullPointerException`

My test is simple (it's not too bad a place to start...)

```java
    @Test
    public void zkControllerDoesMockingInitialisedSuccessfully() throws Exception {

    T2TripBigDaoInterface tripBigDao = createMock(T2TripBigDao.class);
    ZkFieldValidator fieldValidator = createMock(ZkTextFieldValidator.class);
    FieldRangeValidator rangeValidator = createMock(DefaultFieldRangeValidator.class);

    TripController controller = new TripController(tripBigDao, fieldValidator, rangeValidator);


    replay(tripBigDao, fieldValidator, rangeValidator);

    controller.onClick$getTrips(new Event("getTrips"));

    verify(tripBigDao, fieldValidator, rangeValidator);

    // Test purpose: Just get a unit test of the controller running to start with....
}
```

---

Extract of the controller:

```java
public class TripController extends GenericForwardComposer {

....

   public void onClick$getTrips(Event event) throws Exception {
       Sessions.getCurrent().setAttribute("from", from.getValue());
       Sessions.getCurrent().setAttribute("to", to.getValue());

       ....
   }
....
```

---

Extract of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.t2.webservice.controller.alert.TripController.onClick$getTrips(TripController.java:72)
at com.t2.webservice.controller.alert.TripControllerTest.zkControllerDoesMockingInitialisedSuccessfully(TripControllerTest.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the things I dislike most about ZK: their use of singletons and the impact that has on testability.

What I end up doing is removing any references to their singletons ([Sessions](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Sessions.html), [Executions](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Executions.html), [Selectors](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/select/Selectors.html)) from my controllers. In normal operation these singletons get used, but in tests they can be mocked out.

How you go about this is up to you, I still haven't found a pattern I'm in love with.
Here's one idea..

```
public class TripController extends GenericForwardComposer {

    private final TripSessionManager tripSessionManager;

    public TripController() {
        // ZK calls the default constructor
        this(new ZKTripSessionManager());
    }

    protected TripController(TripSessionManager tripSessionManager) {
        this.tripSessionManager = tripSessionManager;
    }

    public void onClick$getTrips(Event event) throws Exception {
        tripSessionManager.setTo(to.getValue());
        tripSessionManager.setFrom(from.getValue());
    }

}
```

Your `TripSessionManager` would then look like this..

```
public interface TripSessionManager {

    void setTo(String to);

    void setFrom(String from);

}
```

With the default ZK implementation relying on the `Sessions` singleton..

```
public ZKTripSessionManager implements TripSessionManager {

    public void setTo(String to) {
        setAttribute("to", to);
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        setAttribute("from", from);
    }

    private void setAttribute(String name, String value) {
        // only valid if called in a ZK managed thread
        Sessions.getCurrent().setAttribute(name, value);
    }

}
```

By abstracting out the implementation, you can test your controller with a mock `TripSessionManager`..

```
@Test
public void test() {
    TripSessionManager mockTripSessionManager = mock(TripSessionManager);
    when(mockTripSessionManager.setTo(anyString()).thenAnswer(...);
    when(mockTripSessionManager.setFrom(anyString()).thenAnswer(...);
    TripController controller = new TripController(mockTripSessionManager);
}
```

You could also imagine different ways of managing these new dependencies (eg: avoid `new ZKTripSessionManager()`) using dependency injection frameworks like Spring or Guice.